# Which is the correct preposition to use with the verb "match"?

Tags: prepositions

Which of the following is correct?

> Match the value in the request field **with** the value in the delivery
>   field.

or

> Match the value in the request field **to** the value in the delivery
>   field.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my understanding, both are valid, but they mean different things.

To *match A with B* means to consider the pair (A, B) a set, or to purposely place them together:

> In the seating arrangements, I matched John with Cynthia and boy, did they have a spirited discussion.
>
> I matched the hyacinths with the zinnias.  Don't they look great together?

To *match A to B* means to find some B that corresponds to the relevant aspect of A:

> To locate the invoice for this order, you have to match the primary key of table ORDER to the foreign key of table INVOICE.
>
> In order for the room to look its best, you have to match the sofa to the carpet.

Answer (score 0):

You hear "match with" much more than "match to", so I'd say "with".

Comment: What you hear more often is not necessarily what is correct for a particular instance.

Comment: I agree, I was just going off of the impression that both could be "correct", so you are left with a subjective decision.